# A method returning a templated varible inside a templated class?

Tags: c++, templates, debugging

Here's this simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class A
{
  public:
    A(T& arg): value(arg) {};

    template <typename U>
    U foo(bool check)
    {
      U a;

      if(check)
      {
        char ex = 'x';
        a = ex;
        return a;
      }

      else
      {
        a = value;
        return value;
      }
    }

  private:
     T value;

};

int main()
{
  int b = 5;
  A <int>a1(b);

  cout <<a1.foo(true) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:39:21: error: no matching function for call to 'A<int>::foo(bool)'
   cout <<a1.foo(true) << endl;
                     ^
main.cpp:11:7: note: candidate: 'template<class U> U A<T>::foo(bool) [with U = U; T = int]'
     U foo(bool check)
       ^~~
main.cpp:11:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:39:21: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'U'
   cout <<a1.foo(true) << endl;
```

It can't find the function when I have explicitly declared it in the class. I tried to cast it to the format it wants. It still gives me error.

I'm new to templates. Where am I going wrong? Please don't just fix my code. Explain to me what you changed in detail.

**Edit** : 
Thanks for your answers. I had someone ask why I'm asking this question. Here's a bit more context,

I'm trying to make a custom-made array which can take any data types from standard data types to arrays and objects. This array index starts from 1 and upwards. However, the zeroth element is an unsigned integer which has the number of elements in this array. I have this function called "GetElementAt" which would fetch the element at a certain index. The problem that I have now is that I want this function to return an unsigned integer (the number of elements) if the element number is 0 and return the data type `T` (one of the elements in the array with the data type T) otherwise.

Comment: What type do you want `typename U` to be?  There's currently no way to know.

Comment: ...or put another way, what **type** do you want `foo(true)` to return?  Your code doesn't specify and your question doesn't specify.  Is it supposed to return a `char`?  Is it supposed to return a `T`?

Comment: Well... That's what I tried to test. So, if it is true, then send a char else send the data type declared to T. That's why I equated it to U before returing it hoping that it would consider the current data type into account.

Comment: I wonder what kind of problem you are trying to solve with this template.

Comment: "if it is true, then send a char else send the data type declared to T." Types don't work this way in C++.

Comment: @n.m.Basically, I'm making my own type of array which can take any data type from objects to standard types. However, the zeroth element is an integer which is the number of elements in this array. Rest would have elements with the data types declared using the template T. There is this function called "GetIndex" which should return the element on an index. So, I want a function to send two types of datatypes - if it is zero, an int otherwise, data type declared in template T.

Comment: "which can take any data type". Types just don't work this way in C++. If you want to reimplement [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any), think carefully again. It's far more complicated than someone who is self-described as "new to templates" can hope to tackle. Besides, you probably don't *need* `std::any`.

Comment: It seems that the question-behind-the-question is "How do I make a function's return type depend on a runtime parameter?"

Answer (score 2):

`foo` is method template inside a template class. So as you have to define the template argument for `a1`, you have to specify the template argument for `foo` too:

```
a1.foo<char>(true);
```

Comment: `foo` being a member function is irrelevant to the problem, same would apply for any free standing template function as well - recommend dropping first sentence.

Comment: @Aconcagua yes is not well explained. I thought his confusion was due to the template argument, so I pointed there are 2 template arguments in total and they need to be specified both, I didn't want to say the second was related to the first

Answer (score 2):

template argument deduction can't be done on the return type. you need specify template the argument

```
a1.foo<int>(true) // if U needs to be an int
```

or use the `T` from the class, you are doing assignment between a variable of type `U` and `T` so it may be what you need.

```
   template <class T>
    class A
    {
      public:
        A(T& arg): value(arg) {};

        T foo(bool check)
        {
            // ...
        }

        // or alternatively:
        template <typename U = T>
        U foo(bool check)
        {
            // ...
        }

      private:
         T value;

};
```

Comment: Oh wow... That's annoying! i didn't know that. Is there anyway to know the return type during runtime? Thanks! :)

Comment: @Vaishnavi type are deduced at complie-time. but maybe you can use the template parameter T from the class instead of having an other one for you membre fonction

Comment: How could we deduce *anything* from `foo(true)` with neither template nor function argument given? Even auto does not help, it is deduced from function return value, but as long as even the latter cannot be deduced...

Comment: @Aconcagua what i meant with using auto was using auto as return type, but it wasn't clear

Comment: What do you mean by "specify template the argument"? I should be able to implement that. Can you please explain that in more detail.

Comment: @Tyker Even that does not help: `U u; return u;` - return type is deduced from inner U, but without template or function parameter, we do not know what the inner U is and thus we do not know that the auto is...

Comment: @Aconcagua replacing the template type by a deduced type. all i saw at that point was the error message but yes U is used in the function so auto doesn't apply is this case

Comment: "use T from the class": Could be used as return type of foo directly, but as default template parameter as well...

Comment: No use in repeating unchanged code. Wanted to show alternative as well, hope it's OK that I just edited it in...

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
template <class T>
class A
{
public:
    A(const T& arg): value(arg) {};

    template <bool check>
    auto foo()
    {
        if constexpr (check) {
            return 'x'; // char
        } else {
           return value; // T
        }
    }

private:
    T value;
};
```

With usage:

```
std::cout << a1.foo<true>() << endl;  // x
std::cout << a1.foo<false>() << endl; // 5
```

Comment: Quite different from original version, which has always the same return type, with return value being initialised from either char or member variable. Not sure if really in sense of question, still interesting alternative approach...